# Hide fields in odoo9 openerp

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want hide fields for user in odoo 9. For example, hide Deadline in Project > Task module. 
Only administrator can see this fields.

Any solution how create group etc. hide_only_admin_see  and in field add this line.

```
<field name="date_deadline" groups="hide_only_admin_see"  />
```

I'm find in source `groups="base.group_no_one", groups="base.group_user"`

but don't understand is it possible create my own group, when add to fiels that only Manager can see this...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1. https://postimg.org/image/rvxi74f51/
2. https://postimg.org/image/b87h1dlhv/
3. https://postimg.org/image/5mzst1wtz/
4. ID from file add to field etc:  groups="**export**.res_groups_84"

Answer (score 0):

On odoo 8, you forbid access to a field to all users (except configuration permissions) in that way:

```
<field name="date_deadline" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="groups">base.group_system</attribute>
</field>
```

To create new group of permissions,
on odoo 8, you can create record for new category like:

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="xxx">
            <field name="name">Name of new category of permissions</field>
            <field name="sequence">200</field>
        </record>
```

You can create new records for groups permission on res_groups:

```
<record model="res.groups" id="hide_only_admin_see">
      <field name="category_id" ref="XXXX"/>
      <field name="name">Usuario</field>
</record>
```

On category_id you must write the ir_module_category you are creating / overridiing.
After this, you have to create a line on your ir.model.access.csv to give correct permissions to the model you want, something like:

```
"access_project.issue","project_issue access","model_project_issue","hide_only_admin_see",1,0,0,0
```

Finally, go to the line and override like:

```
<field name="date_deadline" groups="your_custom_module.hide_only_admin_see"  />
```